# How to say about money "money will appear on account " or "money will be on account" or else?

Tags: phrase-usage, translation

How to say *money will appear on account* or *money will be on account* or else?

Full context example: *We transferred money on account - it will appear no later than the next working day.*

What is more commonly used by native speakers? Is there other phrase commonly used?

Could money *appear on account*, *will be on account* or else?

---

Some technical explanation - transfers of money is not online/real time - what mean you could order transfer but it will be not done by bank at once so the money will available after some days hours on account where you address transfer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd say it:

> *Money transferred to your account will appear no later than the next working day.*

or:

> *Money transferred to your account **will be available** no later than the next working day.*

I don't think there is any need to specify "we", and I think the best proposition to use with *transferred* in this context is *to*.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> The money should appear in your account within one working day.

Comment: You trim little context _we_, _transferred_ and add _should_ - it matches original at 80%.

Comment: @Chameleon: In English (and especially British English) we tend to shy away from making assertions about the future - particularly if there's a risk that a timeline might slip (for example because of a delay in their bank processing the request). "I should be able to have this ready for you by the end of the day" is slightly more idiomatic than "I'll have this ready for by the end of the day", but they both mean the same thing.

Comment: @Chameleon: Similarly "money transferred to your account" and "money appearing in your account" are the same thing - with the latter being slightly more idiomatic. As a native speaker, I would probably say "We **will transfer** your money today" / "the **money should appear** in your account tomorrow". I would never say "the money will have transferred into your account by tomorrow"

Comment: See my context remarks - it is not related to book-keeping it is related to bank account. It this case _money transferred to your account_ != _money appearing in your account_ - the sequence is: 1. you order transfer, 2. bank will transfer and it will appear on account. In book-keeping  both is done at once (almost) in bank accounting they are separated with time period.

Answer (score 1):

The amount *will be credited to* your account or *will become available*...

A commentator has asked for "authorities". For "will become available" see

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/available

and check "Availability policy" here:

http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/dictionary/index-dictionary.html